# The recursive method is getting into deadloop

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple crawler based on `HTMLAgilityPack` and `Fizzler`, in order to check if a keyword is contained anywhere on the webpage and it's corresponding sublinks. Then the same procedure is repeated for all of the sublinks up to 50 level deep. So that the number grows exponentially.

The issue is that I wanted to convert the method that I have written to a recursive one, but it doesn't work - gets stuck after first link, as well as works really slow.

This is what I've done currently:

```
    public static void GetAllLinks(HtmlWeb web, List<string> relevantLinks, string inputLink)
    {
        string mainLink = "http://www.cnet.com";
        Console.WriteLine("Current count of links: " + relevantLinks.Count + "\tCurrent link: " + inputLink);


        HtmlDocument html = web.Load(inputLink);
        HtmlDocument htmlInner = new HtmlDocument();

        html.DocumentNode.Descendants()
            .Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(n => n.Remove());

        var text = htmlInner.DocumentNode.InnerText.ToLower();
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\r\n?|\n", "");
        text = Regex.Replace(text, " {2,}", " ");
        text = text.Trim();

        if (text.Contains("microsoft"))
        {
            if (!relevantLinks.Contains(inputLink))
            {
                relevantLinks.Add(inputLink);
            }
        }

        var linkTagsList = html.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("a").ToList();

        foreach (var linkTag in linkTagsList)
        {
            if (linkTag.Attributes["href"] != null)
            {
                var link = linkTag.Attributes["href"].Value;

                // Check if the link found is the sublink of the main link
                if (!link.Contains(mainLink))
                {
                    // Check if only partial link then concat with main one
                    if (link.Substring(0, 1) == "/")
                    {
                        if (inputLink.Substring(inputLink.Length - 1, 1) == "/")
                            inputLink = inputLink.Substring(0, inputLink.Length - 1);
                        link = inputLink + link;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        link = String.Empty;
                    }
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(link);
                    GetAllLinks(web, relevantLinks, link);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Any hint or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to maintain a visited set.

Comment: And also the current depth (if you want to stop at max 50, you need to know at which depth you are)